# php fractal image generator like stackoverflow's default avatar

Tags: php, image-processing

Is there any php fractal image generating library like stackoverflow's default avatar ?
I want to use it for default avatar like this site.

Comment: independent solution is more good. I think

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stack Overflow avatars are provided by [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/). The default image is not a fractal -- it is generated using a variant of the [Identicon](https://github.com/donpark/identicon) algorithm, which basically just puts together an image using a couple of simple geometric components in a grid.

There is a PHP implementation of the Identicon algorithm available: http://sourceforge.net/projects/identicons/

Comment: The original Identicon algorithm used a 3x3 grid. The variant used by Gravatar is 4x4.

Comment: I want to use this library. But I have faced [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919485/how-can-i-execute-a-script-outside-of-root-directory-by-another-one). Is there any workaround?