# How can I execute a script outside of root directory by another one?

Tags: php

I have a script named `MakeAvatar.php`. And when I pass a argument to it (as GET method), it makes a image (avatar) based on that argument:

```
http://example.com/MakeAvatar.php?id=12345
// Output: 1234.jpg
```

And I can simply save that image like this:

```
file_put_contents("../img/avatar/".$id.".jpg", file_get_contents("http://localhost/MakeAvatar.php?id=$id"));
```

---

Now that script (`MakeAvatar.php`) is out of root directory:

```
\out
    \MakeAvatar.php
\root
    \include
        \register.php
    \img
        \avatar
```

And I cannot open `MakeAvatar` as a http request into `register.php`. I just can access it by this path:

```
$_GET['id'] = $id; // passing
file_put_contents("../img/avatar/".$id.".jpg", file_get_contents("../out/MakeAvatar.php"));
```

But code above doesn't work. Because `file_get_contents()` just opens that script, not execute it. Then the output will be a unclear image:

[image]

Also when I open that image by a editor, it is containing the content of `MakeAvatar.php` (all its codes). So it seems the problem is *passing*.

Well, How can I execute that file?

```
. . . file_get_contents("how can I execute MakeAvatar.php in here ?")
```

---

**Note:** I cannot change the content of `MakeAvatar.php`. Also I cannot change its directory *(I mean I cannot put it into root)*.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need `include` / `require`?

Comment: @JonStirling Look, I can `include()` it, but why? I need to execute it. Because when I execute it (and pass a argument to it) the output will be a image and I save that image. But if I just `include()` it, there isn't any image.

Comment: Rather than making a file itself a script. Make a function held in a file outside of the root directory, include the file and then call the function. Alternatively show us the script and we can see how to compensate to your structure.

Comment: By requiring a GET var that sort of implies that that file *should* be under the docroot (or included in a file under the docroot); if it isn't Apache won't handle it, your PHP won't be parsed and yeah.. it just isn't going to work unless you do something filthy.

Comment: @Matt You are right .. But as I said, I cannot change the content of `MakeAvatar.php`

Comment: @stack can we see the contents of the script? If it is using GET variables there will be a solution using include/require

Comment: @stack Unlike your file_get_contents call, which will pull literally the PHP code as a string, include / require actually runs the code...

Comment: @JonStirling Ok, how can I both pass a argument and run a code?

Comment: @stack if the script is expecting a $_GET variable, then if it's not actually in the URL, you can "fake" it by forcing it, e.g. `$_GET['var'] = 'thevalue';` above the include / require.

Comment: @JonStirling Then the code will be `$_GET['id'] = '$id'; require("../out/MakeAvatar.php");` and what should I put into `file_get_contents()` to save that image?

Comment: @stack I don't know, that depends what the MakeAvatar.php script does.

Comment: @JonStirling *MakeAvatar.php* returns a image. There are two last lines into *MakeAvatar.php* `header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($resized);`

Comment: @stack In that case you probably need to wrap the include / require in [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start) calls so you can get the output into a variable, then do your file_put_contents with that variable instead of your current file_get_contents.

Comment: @JonStirling Look, I'm not sure I get you right .. May you please write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I purpose a dirty solution :

```
exec("php /path/to/your/MakeAvatar.php $id");
```

Comment: I'm not sure too :p it is just a guess

Comment: That's not going to work if MakeAvatar needs access to a $_GET variable.

Comment: imagine if `$id` was `&& rm -Rf --no-preserve-root /`

Comment: Ok, but how can I define `$_GET['id']=$id`? You just passed `$id`. And didn't initialize it to `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

So, going by the comments, MakeAvatar.php required a $_GET variable, and outputs image data directly to stdOut. So, I would assume the following could be make to work (potentially with modification).

```
$_GET['id'] = $id; // passing

ob_start();
require('../out/MakeAvatar.php');
$image = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents("../img/avatar/".$id.".jpg",$image);
```

Note, this is untested, but I think should give you the basis for an workable solution.

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer. But still the output is a unknown (unclear) image.

Comment: I don't believe there is any more help we can give with the code / information we've got. As I said in the answer, it's untested (since it's your code) it can only be used as an idea of how to achieve your goal. From this point you need to start debugging why things aren't running as you expect.

Comment: Also as a note *(I'm not sure it helps or not)*, this is [MakeAvatar.php](http://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/identicons/identicons-1.0.1.zip)